# OSX keyboard shortcut for 'show all'

Tags: keyboard, macos

How can I activate the 'Show all' or back button in a system preference dialog in OSX? E.g.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System Preferences, go to `Keyboard`, then `Shortcuts`.

At the bottom you can enable or disable full keyboard access. Full keyboard access will enable highlighting checkboxes, buttons, etc.

When a control is highlighted, hitting space will have the same effect as clicking on the control.

[image: Screen with highlighting of a button]

Comment: Excellent! I cannot believe that's not the default (or that I was stupid enough to miss it - I'm sure I've enabled that before, pre-Mavericks ...)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> appears to do it, although that just raises further questions ...

Comment: Like in the Finder to go to the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

⌘L, or View menu -> Show All Preferences:

[image: System Prefs > View menu]